# Removable drive .lnk access is denied

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus, virus-removal, removable-media

I'm trying to remove flashdrive shortcut virus in windows 7. When I enter `del *.lnk` in cmd, I get this-

```
Removable Drive <4 GB>.lnk
Access is denied.
```

How should I remove this error?